# confusion with Nested Bem classes

Tags: html, css, class, bem

I have a header with nested classes. How can I write classes name?

Is the following correct?

```
<header class="header">
    <nav class="header__navbar"></nav>
    <div class="header__search__btn">
        <a href="#" class="header__search__btn__link"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="header__search__wrapper">
        <form class="header__search__wrapper__form"></form>
    </div>
    <div class="header__logo"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: I've never heard of BEM, but if this is how it proscribes class names, I don't like it. That's not what class names are supposed to do.

Comment: @MrLister no, this isn't quite how it works, but the `__` is an important part, there should just be one per class name - it's well worth a look, once you get over any subjective "it's ugly" type responses, such as those I had :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

You are right that you should separate out your blocks from your elements with a `__` but once you've done that you shouldn't then be using `__` again in the same class. If you need to use more than one word then use a single hyphen, for example `header__affiliate-logos`.

Let's look at the example cleaned up a bit:

```
<header class="header">
    <nav class="header__navbar"></nav>
    <div class="header__search search">
        <form class="search__form"></form>
        <a href="#" class="search__link"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="header__logo"></div>
</header>
```

What's happened here is that the `header` block has been reduced somewhat to include classes that only logically belong to the header, whereas the `search` block has been separated out into it's own BEM module.

The result is that the classes are much more concise and meaningful and you actually have a full re-usable `search` module that is not tied to the header of the site.

To style the search you'd put your generic search styles into the module, perhaps including the colour of the link or the size of the search input. Then you'd give it header related context in your more specific `header__search`, perhaps positioning it the correct place as per the designs.

It's generally best to avoid all context if possible in BEM modules, particularly in any general block, so the `search` block could just be small-form.

Some more resources here:

[Smashing Magazine - A New Front End Methodology](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/16/a-new-front-end-methodology-bem/)

[CSS Wizardry - MindBEMding](http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/)

[CSS Wizardry - an article with more about context and examples](http://csswizardry.com/2015/06/contextual-styling-ui-components-nesting-and-implementation-detail/)

Note that it isn't technically necessary to include all the search elements within their parent, but it does make more sense to do so.